# I can't do facebook login with windows 8 mobile application

Tags: facebook, windows-8, authentication, windows-phone-8

I am developing a windows 8 phone application with c# and I have to use facebook to login, currently I am use a service to connect to the database. I have the AppID and App secret key. but It failing to execute my facebook login code. My code is available through the link: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Integrate_Facebook_to_Your_Windows_Phone_Application. This codes execute successfully but I am unable to see the login page. 
Could someone please help me?

Comment: I do not know if it is related but on an Android app I am developing the login process has suddenly stopped working. In particular I can't get the user to sign in successfully and get an access token.

Answer (score 0):

please check once app-Id and app secret the same is working for me.